# How to display images from a bootloader?

Tags: operating-system, bootloader

I have a kernel already designed and am now developing a  bootloader. I would like to know, in the bootloader, instead of displaying text, is there any way to display a small image, while the kernel is loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, it's possible, but how to do so will depend completely on your hardware platform and your kernel.

For usual x86-type hardware, have a look here: [Drawing In Protected Mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode). The [Video](http://wiki.osdev.org/Category%3aVideo) category on that Wiki has other valuable resources.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it was possible, but when I started reading about making an os, it only taught about displaying text...